# How to call the Value of split stored in App.Config File in C#

Tags: c#, split, console-application, app-config, appsettings

I have stored the value to split the text file in App.Config file.I am getting problem while passing the value for split with the KEY Name,I am reading the text file with comma "," seperator and storing it in database with index.Help me call the app key into split.

```
 con.Open();
                using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"E:\StudentFileDB\StuNameFile.txt"))
                {
                    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                      string fields = line.Split(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["splitcode"].ToString());


                        cmd = new SqlCommand(StudentInsertQuery, con);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentId", fields[0].ToString());
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentName", fields[1].ToString());
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", fields[2].ToString());
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", fields[3].ToString());
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", fields[4].ToString());
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", fields[5].ToString());
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

///App.Config File
    <add key="splitcode" value="," />
```

Error stating cannot pass string to Error,I want to know to pass the key value inside line.split,It is working when i use directly string[] field=line.split(",");

//compiletime error

string fields = line.Split(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["splitcode"].ToString());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try breaking your problem and see where exactly are you getting the error.

```
// Change This 
string fields = line.Split(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["splitcode"].ToString());
//To This

string s = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["splitcode"].ToString();
char sperator = Convert.ToChar(s);
string[] fields = line.Split(sperator);
```

Now there is a better way to write all this code in one line as well but then you need to understand where the problem is

You are not using string array to store strings. 
You are not using char to split, you're passing a string to split.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem come from the fact that you are providing a string to the [Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8) method that expect a char.

In this case :

```
// Not compiling
line.Split(",");

// Compiling
line.Split(',');
```

Instead of using a string you can use the first char of the string :

```
// TODO : safety checks
string fields = line.Split(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["splitcode"].ToString()[0]);
```

You can also cast the value as a char, but you need to be sure that you only have one char.

```
// TODO : safety checks
string fields = line.Split((char)ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["splitcode"].ToString());
```

Comment: string[] fields = line.Split(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["splitcode"].ToString()[0]); //This solves my Error